# Relay mouse position in iFrame to parent window

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a page **A.html** where I embed **B.html**, I want to get mouse position in A.html, there is a problem, when my mouse clicks on A.html when over the **iframe** element, it does not show me the mouse position

**A.html**

```
<style>
  .iframe_1{height:150px; width: 150px; top:360px; left:365px; overflow:hidden;
            position:absolute;}
</style>
<iframe id="iframe" class="iframe_1" src="http://www.example.com/B.html">
</iframe>
```

**my.js**

```
document.onclick=getMouPo;
function getMouPo(ev){
  if ( ev == null )
    ev = window.event;

  var point = {
    x:0,y:0
  };
  if ( typeof window.pageYOffset != 'undefined'){
    point.x = window.pageXOffset;
    point.y = window.pageYOffset;
  }
  else if(typeof document.compatMode != 'undefined' && document.compatMode != 'BackCompat'){
    point.x = document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
    point.y = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  }
  else if(typeof document.body != 'undefined'){
    point.x = document.body.scrollLeft;
    point.y = document.body.scrollTop;
  }

  point.x += ev.clientX;
  point.y += ev.clientY;
  alert (point.x +","+ point.y);
  return point;
} // getMouPo(ev)
```

Comment: Your question is difficult to understand. I tried to correct it but I don't get it. You should think about editing it

Comment: If both pages are in the same domain, you can access the `iframe` from **A.html** through `window.frames`.

Comment: Thanks Martin Magakian and Guido Gautier.   The problem is that I want alert some message on A.html when click in the <iframe> this area,and both pages maybe not the same domain, is there ohter way to do this?